# jquery this select then next

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a simple slideToggle when an anchor tag is clicked.  The text that should slideToggle is wrapped in a span tag that is coded directly after the anchor tag.  I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
<script>
$('#rp-help-main a').click(function() {
  $(this).next().find("span").slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is a sample html:

```
<div id="rp-add-note">
<h4>Add note tool</h4>
<p>
This tool allows you to <strong>add a note</strong> anywhere in your room.  Simply move your cursor to where you'd like your note to appear and left-click.<a href="#" onclick="return false">expand more</a>  <span>A text box will appear.  Once you type your note choose SAVE and your note will be inserted directly into your room. 
<br /><br />
Move your note using the selection tool.  Simply click on the note and drag it where you'd like it to appear.  To delete, click on the note to view the text box again.  Once the text box appears, click REMOVE TEXT
</span>
 </p>
 </div>

   <div id="rp-undo-tool">
<h4>Undo tool</h4>
<p>
Click on this button at any time to <strong>undo your last action</strong>.  Note:  This will only undo your last action, it will not... <a href="#" onclick="return false">expand more</a> <span>continue to undo previous actions. 
 </span>
 </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: For better results, please define "did not work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that `find('span')`. Then it's working for me:

```
$('#wrapper a').click(function() {

    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/exovos/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery attaches a click handler to `#rp-help-main a`, but no element with that ID exists in the markup you posted.

You will need to modify your jQuery to reference an existing element, or modify your markup to include an element with that ID.

Additionally, your jQuery code may be executed before the element exists in the DOM. It needs to be encapsulated in code that will execute when the page load is complete:

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $('#rp-help-main a').click(function() {
      $(this).next().find("span").slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `Additionally, your jQuery is never executed` is not right. It is executed, but maybe before the elements are parsed by the browser.